# compare date validator validating only date and not the month and month

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using compare validator to validate from date and to date. I want to validate that To date can't be less than From date. I am using

```
     <asp:CompareValidator ID="cmpvDate" runat="server" ControlToCompare="txtDateTo" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="basic"
   ControlToValidate="txtDateFrom" ErrorMessage="To Date can't be less than From date"
  Operator="GreaterThanEqual" ForeColor="red" Type="Date"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

But it is validating only the day and not the month and year.

Any ideas or suggestions please?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to be okay (I tested it and it worked for me), except you should swap from date and to date.

```
<asp:CompareValidator 
    ID="cmpvDate" runat="server" 
    ControlToCompare="FromDate" 
    Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="basic"
    ControlToValidate="ToDate" 
    ErrorMessage="To Date can't be less than From date"
    Operator="GreaterThanEqual" 
    ForeColor="red" Type="Date"/>
```

Post a bit more code, like how you're doing the txtDateTo and txtDateFrom input, maybe it's something there. Otherwise what date settings is your system setup to use, US or UK?